# Using jQuery lazy load plugin and tablesorter plugin with addParser method?

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading, tablesorter

I am using [jQuery Lazy plugin](http://unwrongest.com/projects/lazy/) for lazy loading JS and CSS resources. I am also using [TableSorter jQuery plugin](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) for making tables sortable. Now these two work great with no problem, when I simply define Tablesorter in Lazy plugin and then use Tablesorter like this:

```
$('#table_id').tablesorter();
```

This above works as expected, Tablesorter library is loaded on demand and the HTML table becomes sortable. However, I need to add custom parser to tablesorter like this:

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({ 
  id: 'my_parser', 
  is: function(s) { 
    return false; 
  }, 
  format: function(s) { 
    var result = s.match(/([0-9]+)/);
    if (result == null) return 0;
    return parseInt(result[0]);
  }, 
  type: 'numeric' 
});
```

Problem with above addParser code is, that I get error that "$.tablesorter has no method 'addParser'". And it doesn't make difference, if the TableSorter plugin is already loaded or not. Lazy plugin overwrites $.tablesorter with its own function and doesn't allow for this king of call - I suppose.

Example of this [behaviour can be seen here in this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ds9R5/).

Can anyone help me ? I would very much appreciate any help or thought. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looking at the lazy plugin's source code, I can't find any hint that an event would be triggered after loading has finished. But that's exactly what you would need here, since you do want the configuration call to be deferred until something actually *loads* the library.

Comment: You should consider using another loader plugin like [Yepnope](http://yepnopejs.com/) or [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/). Both provides callbacks functionnality when scripts are finished loading.

Comment: @DidierG. Both of these libraries do look a lot better than `jquery.lazy.js`

Comment: @DidierG. - I don't need callback function, actually, I don't even want it. I am very much satisfied with Lazy plugin which works perfectly - loads JS and CSS only and ONLY when it is actually used. Both Yepnope and RequireJS will load resources always, whether they are actually used in page or not. Lazy plugin is great, however it apparantly doesn't work correctly when no selector is used and the library is called directly, such as $.tablesorter.addParser(); ...

Comment: It's not true that these libraries will load resources *always*. It wouldn't even make sense, if you think about it: You don't really need a library to do unconditional loading. Take a closer look at *Yepnope*, it is very small and can do exactly what you need.

Comment: @Tomalak What I like about jquery.lazy.js is that it works seemlessly.  I just supply it with bunch (tens) of resources when the page starts loading. And those resources get never load ! That's a good thing for me. And whenever I make a call to some of the resources, e.g. $('#table').tablesorter(); Lazy plugin makes all the work for me in the background - it loads some of the needed resources and then executes my command. This can be achieved with Yepnope, but with some additional code, when I would have to use callbacks. But Lazy plugin works seemlessly, no need to use callbacks at all...

Comment: @Frodik That's nice and all, but obviously its not what you *need*, so there is no use in defending it. ;) You can go ahead and hack the source of `jquery.lazy.js` to add callback support, or you can use a library that already has callback support. Bottom line: You won't get around callbacks, no matter how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to prove my point that [yepnope.js](http://yepnopejs.com/) could easily do what you need (i.e. conditional loading of the tablesorter plugin if there are any sortable tables around):

```
$(function () {
 yepnope({
    test    : $("table.sortable").length,
    yep     : "/resources/jquery.tablesorter.js",
    complete: function () {
      $.tablesorter.addParser({
        // whatever;
      });
      $("table.sortable").tablesorter();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I agree with you, this would work, however it would be very unpractical in my scenario. I would have to use this long code at every place I want to initialize some sortable table. What I like about Lazy plugin is that my list of resources is centralized in one file and I don't have to deal with them every time I need to use some of the resources in any of my pages. So you are right, your solution works, but it wouldn't help me much. But thanks for your effort.

Comment: I don't see how could *not* have all your resources in one place/file with this approach as well. But yes, maybe you would have to change some of your source code. The point is: Unless I'm overlooking something in the source code of `jquery.lazy.js` (which is entirely possible), it simply can't do what you want.

Comment: Just for clarification why I can't use yepnope like you demonstrated - I have many pages with tables and each table is initialized on its own page with some tablesorter-specific options. And these options have to be specified in this page inline because they are dynamically generated and I can't put them all in one JS file when I would use yepnope. Because I would have to know all the table IDs and wouldn't be able to supply them with specific tablesorter options if it would be placed all in one JS file.

Comment: @Frodik I see what you mean. However, if you put the above script into a `.js` and load that right after jQuery and yepnope.js, the `.tablesorter()` call would work perfectly normally throughout your code. Just add a `.sortable` class to all your sortable tables (or use some other means to identify them). There would not be very much to change - you certainly don't have to initialize all sortable tables in the `complete` callback, if that's what you're thinking.

Comment: That's what I can't do - have one general CSS class like .sortable because I need to initialize each table individually, because I use specific options for each table like $('table').tablesorter({ ... })

Comment: @Frodik You don't understand. You can keep all your specific initialization code right where it is. The CSS class (or whatever) would just be there to identify whether tablesorter should be loaded *at all*.

Comment: Ok, now I got it, sorry for slow brain. Thanks for patience too.

Comment: @Frodik Never mind. :) If you think about it, with `yepnope.js` you would not even need the callback, since after the `test`, the tablesorter plugin will be loaded - you can do all tablesorter configuration in the subsequent code like you would do it normally. All you have to do is load yepnope as the first thing after jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal you get this error. They way the Lazy plugin works is to create a proxy for the `name` you provide in the options.

So actually `$.tablesorter` is (looking in the console):

```
$.tablesorter:
function proxy() {
    var self = this;
        arg = arguments;

        if( $.lazy.archive[src].status === 'loaded' ) {

            $.each(this,function(){
                $(this)[name].apply(self,arg);
            });

        } else if ( $.lazy.archive[src].status === 'loading' ) {
            $.lazy.archive[src].que.push({'name':name,'self':self,'arguments':arg});

        ...
```

If the plugin has already loaded into the `$.lazy.archive`, it applies it to the elements you called `tablesorter()` on, otherwise it first loads the plugin and then apllies it.

So you don't have the original namespace the plugin normally provides and you can't, in your context, use `$.tablesorter.addParser`.

Comment: Is there any way, how could I call $.tablesorter.addParser() ?

Comment: Not with the Lazy plugin i'm afraid

Comment: Ok, or any other lazy loading plugin for jQuery which would work like jquery.lazy.js ? But please no yepnope - regarding my discussion here with Tomalak about yepnope and why I can't use it....